# Adding an image in front of List Item

Tags: html, css

How can I add an icon in front of a specific list item?

```
<ul class="rightNav2">
    <li id="homeLnk"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have the following style for the list items already and I want to add a specific icon in front of one of the items. The image however does not appear.

```
.rightNav2 li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 6px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  color: white;
}

.rightNav2 #homeLnk {
    list-style-image: url('/images/homeIcon.png');
}
```

Comment: Best way? It depends. Each person coming here could have a different opinion.

Comment: I re-worded it a bit...thanks for the insight there man...I wholeheartedly agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods to add an image to a list item.

Here is one using a background image. http://jsfiddle.net/p05g14zm/

```
rightNav2 li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 6px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.rightNav2 #homeLnk {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ4nM.jpg?s=32&amp;g=1');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

---

## Problem

---

> The list-style-image property determines whether the list marker is
>   set with an image, and accepts a value of "none" or a URL that points
>   to the image: ~[css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/list-style/)

This means that, rather than applying this styling to the `li`, you're meant to apply it to the parent `ul`. Something like:

```
ul {
    list-style-image: url(images/bullet.png);
}
```

So you can't place it on a single element using just this syntax (unless you wanted to use the `:first-child` selector (*not tested*))

---

## My Solution

---

This solution may or may not be of use to you, but it's using pseudo effects (meaning no real 'extra' elements need to be added). The pseudo element would also be clickable, too (with no need of worrying about image sizing, as this would do it for you):

```css
.rightNav2 li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 6px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  /*only for demo*/
}
.rightNav2 #homeLnk a:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  left: -20px;
  top:0;
  position: absolute;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/20/20);
}
```

```html
<ul class="rightNav2">
  <li id="homeLnk"><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">another link</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">and another link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.rightNav2 #homeLnk:before {
    content: url('/images/homeIcon.png');
}
```

Also you might want to make sure that the image path is correct.

Comment: you *might* want to check your positioning of this element

Comment: do you mean specifying position property? please explain.

Comment: Try running this with an image and see. ;P

Answer (score 1):

Please check out my codepen... I believe this may help you:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myRWmZ

html:

```
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<ul>
  <li>Link 1</li>
  <li class="home">Link 2</li>
  <li>Link 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li.home::before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f015";
  margin-right: 3px;
}

li.home {
  margin-left: -18px;
}
```

So what I did was place an icon using the :before selector. The margin adjustments are meant to ensure that each of the list items still align properly.

Answer (score 1):

The css below would add an icon to the left of the home li element.

```
.rightNav2{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.rightNav2 li{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.rightNav2 #homeLnk {
  padding-left: 35px; 
  /* padding-left above is the width of the icon plus any whitespace between text */
  min-height:10px;
  /* min-height above is the height of the icon */
  background-image: url('/images/homeIcon.png') no-repeat center left;
}
```

I would as in the answer above recommend considering icon fonts if this a responsive site.
Background images on zoom can become very grainy.