# How to change default bulletdots and add an image instead

Tags: html, css

I am new to css and I am trying to change the bullet style of ul>li as follows:

[image]

Sorry for the less quality image, **it is a green tick inside a circle**.

My code so far is:

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style-type: square;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
   <li>Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</li>
   <li>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit.</li>
   <li>
      Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
      irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
     eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: You can use pseudo class to create this instead of default `list-style`s

Comment: Please refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27843063/adding-an-image-in-front-of-list-item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, check the given snippet on how to change the bullet styles with an image using pseudo classes.

I have used `::before` here to append the tick image before each `li`.

Let me know if this works.

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: flex;
}

li::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    min-width: 15px;
    background-image: url('https://www.citypng.com/public/uploads/preview/-316225804095zek9ufozk.png');
    background-size: 70%;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid green;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</li>
   <li>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit.</li>
   <li>
      Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
      irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
     eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, let me check this in my code

Answer (score 1):

You can do as

```
<ul class="my-image">
   <li>Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</li>
   <li>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit.</li>
   <li>
      Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
      irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
     eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
     </li>
 </ul>
```

then in css you can style it using list-style-image: url('your-image.png');

```
ul.my-image{
 list-style-image: url('your-image.png');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, let me check this in my code

Comment: My resource image doesn't have a round border. Hence I need to go with the above answer. Thanks for your reply though.